# Java date is giving me format mm/dd/yyyy where jquery datepicker date format is dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: java, jquery, date, datepicker

I have an odd issue with date format.
Like, i'm using jquery date picker which is set to format dd/mm/yy.
so, when i'm filling the field with 01/09/2015, it should mean the date is 1st sep, 2015.
But, I see when I receive the filed in controller as a Date, the actual date looks like Fri Jan 09 00:00:00 IST 2015. This is not what I want, I want the date as
1st Sep, 2015. Please help me on what i'm missing.
Below is the code snippet for your reference-
**jsp**

```
 function() {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            maxDate : 0,
            changeMonth : true,//this option for allowing user to select month
            changeYear : true, //this option for allowing user to select from year range
            showOn : "button",
            buttonImage : "<c:url value="resources/images/calendar.gif"/>",
            buttonImageOnly : true,
            buttonText : "Select date",
            showOtherMonths : true,
            selectOtherMonths : true
        })

    });

<form:form method="post" id="inbound_form" modelAttribute="formObject" action="submit" onsubmit="return validateInboundAdd()" >
<form:input class="datepicker required" style="height:14px"
                                id="dateReceived" size="10" maxlength="10"  type="text" readonly="readonly" value="${dateReceivedContinue}"
                                path="dateReceived" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)"/>
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submit" , method = RequestMethod.POST , params="Save ")
    public String submit(@ModelAttribute("formObject") modelObject modelObject,

    System.out.println("received date -"+modelObject.getDate_received());  // This is giving me the mm/dd/yyyy output, which I want as dd/mm/yyyy. This is getter of the date field 'dateReceived'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the pattern over the date_received field in model formObject, so that spring can handle the conversion properly

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Hope it will work!!!

Comment: Yes I think this will work, "mm" is minutes. so the date format was not valid. The month code is "MM" and I know that 'mm' will give strange results. @user3378974

Comment: it worked perfectly !! Thanks a lott. But again, as this field was a path attribute, @dattimeformat worked. But what to do when a particular field is not a path attribute ? Like consider in my case 'dateReceived' is not an object attribute, it is a plain normal field that i'm submitting to controller , then how can i change the data format to accept it dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: we could use  @InitBinder for above problem.